# Ubuntu 12.10 not available to boot into

Tags: installation, 12.10, windows-7

So I downloaded 12.10 today, burned the image to dvd, have attempted to install sevreal times, I get through the entire process, once I remove dvd and reboot, the system automatically goes into win 7, no option to boot into ubuntu, what am I doing wrong?

I am selecting "boot along side windows".

Answer (score 0):

Try holding Shift while booting after you've installed. If a screen pops up showing a list of options for devices to boot into, then you've installed everything correctly. Just use the arrow keys to navigate over to ubuntu and press enter.

If that doesn't work, or if nothing happens at all when you press shift, we'll need to manually create a new partition.

1. boot into windows 7, go to Start> right-click Computer> Manage.
2. Once in management tools, on the menu on the left side, click on disk management.
3. On your main drive (C:) right click on the main volume and select resize volume. If I were you, I'd shrink it by at least 60GB.
4. reboot into your Ubuntu Installation
5. once you get to the location selection, choose "Something Else".
6. once in the menu, select the space you've freed up and create a new partition. In the menu, select swap space. If your computer has over 4 GB of RAM, you'd be fine even without a swap space. with less RAM, I'd go for about 2GB. If you can't find the empty space, go into the dropdown menu in the upper left hand corner and select the right drive.
7. using the remaining space, create a partition in the ext4 file system.
8. Once the ext4 partition has been created, click on it and then press install.

Good Luck!